# Remove language from VB.Net form

Tags: vb.net, forms, localization

I accidentally added a Language to my form. Instead of editing the "Italian" profile, I edited the "Italian - Italy" profile. Now when I build I have an additional folder called it-IT. I do not want this folder, but i dont seem to be able to find how to remove the "Italian - Italy" Language from my form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This seems to work.
1. Insure that all your forms are set to the default language. (even if they are click on default anyway.)
2. Go to the App Project Properties.
3. Click on assembly info.
4. Same as step 1. At the bottom. (It has some sort of toggle)